# Javascript array access outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I'm trying to get json data with `$.getJSON` and it's working fine.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var MainArray = new Array();
    $.getJSON('check-location.php?onload=true', function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i){
            MainArray[i] = result[i].CountryName;
        });
    });

    $(".drop-down").append("<div>" + MainArray[0] + "</div>");
});
```

I'm trying to assign it to array for later usage, but when I try to access it and display it I get `undefined`.

I get all the data for sure, but when I assign it to `MainArray` I cant access it outside the `$.each` function and I've no idea why.

Comment: Just a note. Go for `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because Ajax is *asynchronous*, you are trying to append a non-existent value:

```
$.getJSON('check-location.php?onload=true', function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(i){
        MainArray[i] = result[i].CountryName;
    });
    $(".drop-down").append("<div>" + MainArray[0] + "</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, the `MainArray` isn't updated  until the data is successfully returned.

But, the line

```
$(".drop-down").append("<div>" + MainArray[0] + "</div>");
```

will have already executed before the `$.getJSON` is completed...hence it is `undefined`.

You should move this somewhere and execute it when your data has returned, ie. in the callback

Answer (score 0):

Like every body said, because its an asynchronous request
you can turn that off (not a very good practice, but it will fix the problem)

Add this before the $.getJSON call

```
$.ajax({ async: "false" });
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help guys.